# Correlated SQL Query using With Clause

Tags: oracle, subquery, correlated-subquery

I am trying to modify below query :

```
SELECT START_END.*, START_END.LOAD_TIME_END - START_END.LOAD_TIME_START
FROM
(
  SELECT START.JOB_ID, START.LOAD_TIME_START, END.LOAD_TIME_END
  FROM
  (
    SELECT JOB_ID,LOAD_TIME AS LOAD_TIME_START
    FROM JOB_CTRL_RECON JCR
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT JOB_ID AS JOB_ID_S, MAX(RECON_ID) AS S_MAX_RECON_ID
      FROM job_ctrl_recon
      where job_id in ('1','2')
      and count_type = 'Source'
      GROUP BY JOB_ID
    ) SMAX
    ON JCR.JOB_ID = SMAX.S_MAX_RECON_ID
    AND JCR.RECON_ID = SMAX.RECON_ID
  ) START
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT JOB_ID,LOAD_TIME AS LOAD_TIME_END FROM JOB_CTRL_RECON JCR INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT JOB_ID AS JOB_ID_T, MAX(RECON_ID) AS T_MAX_RECON_ID
      FROM job_ctrl_recon
      where job_id in ('1','2')
      and count_type = 'Target'
      GROUP BY JOB_ID
    ) TMAX
    ON JCR.JOB_ID = TMAX.T_MAX_RECON_ID
    AND JCR.RECON_ID = TMAX.RECON_ID
  ) END
  ON START.JOB_ID = END.JOB_ID
) START_END
```

to a query using with clause as below :

How can i eliminate the multiple use of `where job_id in ('1','2')` using with clause something like below :

```
WITH A AS 
(
  SELECT JOB_ID FROM JOB_CTRL_RECON WHERE JOB_ID IN ('60','67')
)
SELECT START_END.*, START_END.LOAD_TIME_END - START_END.LOAD_TIME_START
FROM 
(
  SELECT START.JOB_ID, START.LOAD_TIME_START, END.LOAD_TIME_END
  FROM
  (
    SELECT JOB_ID,LOAD_TIME AS LOAD_TIME_START
    FROM JOB_CTRL_RECON JCR
    INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT JOB_ID AS JOB_ID_S, MAX(RECON_ID) AS S_MAX_RECON_ID
      FROM job_ctrl_recon
      where job_id in (????)
      and count_type = 'Source'
      GROUP BY JOB_ID
    ) SMAX
    ON JCR.JOB_ID = SMAX.S_MAX_RECON_ID
    AND JCR.RECON_ID = SMAX.RECON_ID
  ) START
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT JOB_ID,LOAD_TIME AS LOAD_TIME_END
    FROM JOB_CTRL_RECON JCR
    INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT JOB_ID AS JOB_ID_T, MAX(RECON_ID) AS T_MAX_RECON_ID
      FROM job_ctrl_recon
      where job_id in (????)
      and count_type = 'Target'
      GROUP BY JOB_ID
    ) TMAX
    ON JCR.JOB_ID = TMAX.T_MAX_RECON_ID
    AND JCR.RECON_ID = TMAX.RECON_ID
  ) END
  ON START.JOB_ID = END.JOB_ID
) START_END, A
WHERE START_END.JOB_ID = A.JOB_ID
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain what the select should achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `WITH`, you may be able to simplify the code using a `KEEP` with an analytic function.  The code is a bit weird at first, but it lets you only specify the JOB_ID once and it only has to read from the table once.

```
--Load time start and end for each JOB_ID, based on the latest RECON_ID.
select
    job_id,
    max(load_time_start) load_time_start,
    max(load_time_end) load_time_end,
    max(load_time_end) - max(load_time_start) diff
from
(
    --First and last load time for each set of rows, with some debug data.
    select job_id, count_type, recon_id, load_time
        ,last_value(case when count_type = 'Source' then load_time else null end)
            over (
                partition by job_id, count_type
                order by recon_id
                rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
            ) load_time_start
        ,last_value(case when count_type = 'Target' then load_time else null end)
            over (
                partition by job_id, count_type
                order by recon_id
                rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
            ) load_time_end
    from job_ctrl_recon
    where job_id in (1,2)
)
group by job_id
order by job_id;
```

For this table and data:

```
create table job_ctrl_recon(job_id number, recon_id number, count_type varchar2(100), load_time date);

alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-RR';

insert into job_ctrl_recon
select 1, 400, 'Source', '24-Feb-18' from dual union all
select 1, 40,  'Source', '23-Feb-18' from dual union all
select 1, 89,  'Target', '25-Feb-18' from dual union all
select 1, 8,   'Target', '25-Feb-18' from dual union all
select 2, 700, 'Source', '24-Feb-18' from dual union all
select 2, 8,   'Source', '23-Feb-18' from dual union all
select 2, 567, 'Target', '25-Feb-18' from dual union all
select 2, 45,  'Target', '25-Feb-18' from dual union all
select 2, 678, 'Target', '25-Feb-18' from dual;

commit;
```

These are the results:

```
JOB_ID   LOAD_TIME_START   LOAD_TIME_END   DIFF
------   ---------------   -------------   ----
1        2018-02-24        2018-02-25      1
2        2018-02-24        2018-02-25      1
```

Comment: It fetches the load_time_end as null

Comment: @Math590 If you add some sample data I can debug it.

Comment: Data is as below:                                                                               JOB_ID RECON_ID COUNT_TYPE LOAD_TIME
1 400 Source 24-Feb-18
1 40 Source 23-Feb-18
1 89 Target 25-Feb-18
1 8 Target 25-Feb-18
2 700 Source 24-Feb-18
2 8 Source 23-Feb-18
2 567 Target 25-Feb-18
2 45 Target 25-Feb-18
2 678 Target 25-Feb-18

Comment: @Math590 I rewrote my answer using the data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hope it helps. Thanks.

```
old:     where job_id in (????)
new:     where job_id in (select JOB_ID from A)
```